# ASP.NET MVC book/tutorial for a Non-EF/LINQ/ORM Developer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-access

I have been using WebForms until now and now wish to learn MVC. However all the online sources that I can reach prefer employing Entity Framework for database examples. I do not will to discuss whether EF (or ORM in general) is good or bad, but I want to learn MVC not any ORM. So can you suggest a source (online or book) that focuses on MVC and uses some more *classic* data access methods (e.g. DataReaders) or simpler abstraction layers (some collections encapsulating data)?

Comment: define "classic data access methods"

Comment: although i strongly believe it should be obvious from the context, i updated the question a bit.

Comment: While it is completely possible to use ASP.NET MVC with ADO.NET, there is very little compelling reason to do so.  I am in that exact situation with my current client and it's not at all enjoyable how much time I'm *wasting* futzing with the data layer of the application.  Using an ORM makes development go so much faster (once the learning curve issues are overcome).  What I'm trying to say is that there is a *very good* reason so many ASP.NET MVC samples use EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework is not necessary for use with MVC - it is just one method. You can pick up any of the major MVC books (I recommend those written by John Galloway, et al or Dino Esposito) and just pass by the section specifically talking about EF (if the book indeed does have such a section).

Comment: I agree. A well-written book will discuss the layers better than a book that can't separate concerns very well. The goal of MVC is to keep parts in the presentation layer separate from the business or data layers.